В vscode не работает плавный скролл при определённых значениях настройки window.zoomLevel
Настройка window.zoomLevel у меня всегда стояла на значении 1. Недавно я увидел, что в vscode есть плавный scroll. Я прописал команду "editor.smoothScrolling": true, но почему-то плавная прокрутка не заработала. Я перепробовал все способы, переустанавливал vscode, но ничего не помогло. В итоге пошел копаться в своих настройках и понял, что при некоторых значениях настройки window.zoomLevel плавный скролл у меня просто не работает. Я попробовал приближение от 0 до 3 и получилось, что при значениях

0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5,
1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 3

плавный скролл работает, а при значениях

1, 1.4, 1.9, 2.1, 2.3, 2.9

не работает. С чем это может быть связано?
